# Not booting to portable USB DVD Drive, though showing in Boot menu?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, boot, bios, dvd

I have an AMD Duron, BIOS version is 2001 (an old PC). I want to do a clean install of Win XP. When i connect the USB DVD drive, it detects in the Boot Menu-F8, but soon the message comes - Insert Boot Disk, even though Boot Disk is already avialable in the usb DVD Drive and then jumps to Novell Netware.I also checked the Boot Disk in other PC, it was bootable.

How can i do a clean install of Win XP through my usb DVD drive? i also diabled the Hard Disk option in BIOS and selected first Boot device as USB CDROM,since USB DVD not available.

Comment: Can't you install using a USB stick instead? use something like [WinToFlash](http://wintoflash.com/download/en/).

Comment: 2001 BIOS supports booting from USB ? i would recommend him to upgrade the bios if he knows how.